# how does scaling policy work with sagemaker endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-auto-scaling

based on the docs provided here , https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/async-inference/Async-Inference-Walkthrough.ipynb
I'm defining an autoscaling policy for my sagemaker endpoint ( sample code below) . I have specified from 0 - 3 capacity for the scalable config. I understand, this will only scale to maximum capacity of 3 when needed and or else it will scale down to 0 after a period. from cost perspective, when it is scale down to 0 , is there any charges? also, what how does it handle where , it scales to maximum capacity and there are more requests in the queue?

```
client = boto3.client("application-autoscaling")
resource_id = ("endpoint/" + endpoint_name + "/variant/" + "variant1")

# Configure Autoscaling on asynchronous endpoint down to zero instances
response = client.register_scalable_target(
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker",
    ResourceId=resource_id,
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",
    MinCapacity=0,
    MaxCapacity=3,
)

response = client.put_scaling_policy(
    PolicyName="Invocations-ScalingPolicy",
    ServiceNamespace="sagemaker", 
    ResourceId=resource_id,  # Endpoint name
    ScalableDimension="sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount",  # only Instance Count
    PolicyType="TargetTrackingScaling",  
    TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
        "TargetValue": 5.0,  # The target value for the 
        SageMakerVariantInvocationsPerInstance
        "CustomizedMetricSpecification": {
            "MetricName": "ApproximateBacklogSizePerInstance",
            "Namespace": "AWS/SageMaker",
            "Dimensions": [{"Name": "EndpointName", "Value": endpoint_name}],
            "Statistic": "Average",
        },
        "ScaleInCooldown": 600,   
        "ScaleOutCooldown": 300
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The autoscaling policy( and scale down to zero) is based on the `TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration` you define. In this particular scenario, we use the `ApproximateBacklogSize` to determine the scaling. For instance, if the number of requests in the managed queue is beyond a certain threshold we automatically step scale instance count which works very similar to AutoScaling in EC2.
I'd recommend you to check the examples here in the [HuffingFace-Async](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/improve-high-value-research-with-hugging-face-and-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-inference-endpoints/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=improve-high-value-research-with-hugging-face-and-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-inference-endpoints) and [CV-Async](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-computer-vision-inference-on-large-videos-with-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-endpoints/) where we go over the different metrics you can use to set for AutoScaling and respective graphs of CloudWatch metrics.

Thanks,
Raghu

Note: I work for AWS but my opinions are my own

Comment: thank you. do you know, if I can set this up via terraform. I was using lambda to set it up for now ( code sample in the question)

Comment: @ozil - You will using the regular autoscaling config outlined in the doc here(https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_target)  to configure it for the SageMaker Async endpoint. There are no specifics for SageMaker.

First, you define the "aws_appautoscaling_target" with minimum and maximum capacities. Then go ahead and define your "TargetTrackingScaling" in the autoscaling policy